# Could not resolve name when debug CUDA kernel

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

I have problem to debug CUDA kernel. Some variables can't be evaluated in debugger. After a lot of investigating and simplify project and code I have very simple project that contain main application call to host function in DLL where call to kernel.
The kernel code actually created with project wizard of Visual Studio.
In addition I have EMPTY .cu file. When its included to build I have a problem.
When this file excluded from build - everything is ok.
Size of dll debug version with empty file is 92 kb and without 90kb.

My setup is
Windows 7 Pro x64
VS2010 Pro
NVIDIA Nsight VS Edition 3.2.2
CUDA SDK 5.5
NVIDIA driver 331.82

Comment: What's exact your question? I only see a list of your problems? Also please provide more informations, your simple project for example.

Comment: My problem is debugging code. I can't forward with my project without debugging code and evaluate variables.  I can share full solution (12 files in 5kb zip). Link to google drive is ok?

Comment: Don't put external links in your question.  When those links become invalid, the question becomes useless for future readers.  Instead, distill your problem down to something short that can be completely posted in the question. It's likely that in the process of doing this reduction, you may discover the problem or key issue yourself.

Comment: I start from solution include 5 projects and about 400 files. Also empty file originally include code. I compare my problematical project with project created by wizard as is and don't find difference. I don't understand how empty source file increase binary by 2K and break debug information.

Comment: This question is perfectly clear to people who have used CUDA and who spend a minute reading the (valiant effort but struggling :) non-native speaker's English.  Don't close questions frivolously.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found root of problem and workaround solution.
The problem happen when solution is complex and include several cpp and cu files.
Because this required "Relocatable Device Code". Otherwise GPU code can't be divided to several CU files.

[CU file passed for compilation to NVCC that perform preprocessing and divide code to host and gpu. After that host code compiled with VC compiler and gpu continue with nvcc.](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/#full-cuda-compilation-trajectory)

When CU file doesn't include any GPU code aka `__device__` functions the debug info is broken.
So workaround is add dummy function in such kind CU file:

```
__device__ void dummy1()
{
}
```

Comment: Despite the question which is a bit awkward, I experienced the same difficulty debugging CUDA using nSight while compiling with rdc flag, 
I solved that problem by unite all the compilation files into one single file and exclude the rdc flag.

Answer (score 0):

Despite this question being downvoted, I encountered the same issue as well and after a bit of investigation it turned out that it was happening when I have "Configuration Properties | CUDA C/C++ | Common | Generate Relocatable Device Code" set to "Yes", which is quite crucial setting for me. Setting it to "No" solved the issue, though I have no idea why.